# Symfony4/Doctrine - mapping '_id' form data attribute directly to entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to submit a POST request containing, amongst other things, 'company_id'.

I want to map this to the property 'Company' of a Doctrine/Symfony4 entity. This field is stored in the 'company_id' column.

My form is pretty vanilla and uses the following to map the incoming request:

```
        ->add('company_id', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Company::class,
        ])
```

The problem is, my model class only has the methods 'getCompany' and 'setCompany' which leads to the following error:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Neither the property \"company_id\" nor one of the methods \"getCompanyId()\", \"companyId()\", \"isCompanyId()\", \"hasCompanyId()\", \"__get()\" exist and have public access in class \"App\\ServiceProviderBundle\\Entity\\Offer\"."
}
```

I've made a workaround by creating some proxy methods (e.g. 'getCompanyId' which proxies directly to 'getCompany'), but this feels hacky and incorrect and there must be a way to make this mapping directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 ->add('company', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Company::class,
 ])
```

Because I think that in your entity there is a property called `company` and not `company_id`, `company_id` is the column name into your database

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've tried this already alas - gives me the following:

`{
 Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null
}`

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a bit of intermediary config that I can add to create this mapping. I'm just not seeing it!

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution - I created an intermediate 'Data Transfer Object' class to do the mapping for me. It has a 'getOfferEntity()' function that returns the Object entity.